# Using printf with netcat

Tags: pipe, netcat, printf

I've made a small command to send a TCP message to an "IP-relay-unit" that can toggle the outputs.

```
printf "setstate,1:1,1\r" | nc ip.ip.ip.ip port
```

This actually works fine, sometimes. Since the printf worked on both linux and mac, I thought it had to do something with netcat. I noted that using -v on netcat improved the amount of times it went right, but this seems like a very dull workaround.

I later found the nc -i option, to add a timeout of 1 sec, which hasn't yet caused an error (on both Linux or OSX), though it does decrease the execution time and still isn't a 100% clean fix.

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) actually shows that piping into the nc command can be done, it doesn't mention any possible race conditions.

Is this expected behaviour? And is there a clean way of fixing this? (like "--only-send-when-connection-is-complete") or can I actually check if it's a race condition?

Comment: many IoT small devices will be slow to connect and accept data, especially if tried several times a second. Your printf is not at fault. You might try nc's `-w` option to change the timeout to connect.

Comment: @meuh Hmm, good point actually! I was worried this was a "bug" in Unix, that it would send before connecting. But some devices may indeed not directly accept data after connecting. So using a 1sec delay would work always (if the device will accept it then) and it will not be bound to the speed of the actual connecting.

Comment: Long story short, it will get send after connecting. But some devices do not support that? 1sec delay is a valid fix. Do you want me to accept the current answer to mark it fixed, or would you prefer creating an answer out of your comment?

Comment: It might be useful to others for you to create an answer of what works for you. Normally, writing to a network device  immediately after connecting should work. Your device is just a little slow and needs special care for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there is an active connection with:

```
nc -v <HOST> <PORT> </dev/null; echo $?
```

If the above command, returns you the value `0`, then the connection is successful and you can `printf` your message, otherwise (value is `1`), then you know that your connection is refused or timed-out etc.